# PHP shift right

Tags: java, php, bit-manipulation

i am trying to implement DataOutputStream in php 
(DataOutputStream from java language)
in java code they shift right variables like this >>>

in php i can only shift like this >>

how can i do this in php ?

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [implement the behavior of the unsigned right shift operator `>>>` with the signed shift operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) like this:

> The value of `n>>>s` is `n` right-shifted `s` bit positions with zero-extension. If `n` is positive, then the result is the same as that of `n>>s`; if `n` is negative, the result is equal to that of the expression `(n>>s)+(2<<~s)` if the type of the left-hand operand is *int*, and to the result of the expression `(n>>s)+(2L<<~s)` if the type of the left-hand operand is *long*. The added term `(2<<~s)` or `(2L<<~s)` cancels out the propagated sign bit.

Comment: so this is what i have to do 

  
  private function shiftRight3($a ,$b){
    if(is_numeric($a) && $a < 0){
      return $a >> $b +(2<<~$b);
    }else{
      return $a >> $b;
    }
  }

Comment: No, not exactly. All you need to do is shift and mask to the required number of bits.

Comment: hey EJP 
can u provide an example please ?

Answer (score 1):

In masked form for any platform (32bit, 64bit... future as long as `PHP_INT_MAX` is defined) which would perhaps offer a performance benefit (no branching):

```
function uintRShift($uint,$shift)
{
    //if ($shift===0) return $uint;
    //PHP_INT_MAX on 32 =7FFFFFFF, or zero & 32 ones
    $mask=PHP_INT_MAX>>($shift-1);
    return $uint>>$shift&$mask;
}
```

The mask setup puts all zeros for the left-most `$shift` bits of `$uint`.  *Note:* Uncomment the first line if you want to be able to/tolerant of zero shifting a negative/large number (since the mask will modify a negative/large number even with `$shift=0`).

The unit testing code to show it's working in 32 bit:

```
class UintRShiftTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
   public function provide_shifts() {
      return array(
         /*   start         shift       end*/
          array(0,          4,          0)
         ,array(0xf,        4,          0)
         ,array(0xff,       4,          0xf)
         ,array(0xfffffff,  4,          0xffffff)
         ,array(0xffffffff, 4,          0xfffffff)
         ,array(-1,         4,          0xfffffff)//Same as above
         ,array(0,          1,          0)
         ,array(0xf,        1,          0x7)
         ,array(-1,         1,          0x7fffffff)
         );
   }

   /**
    * @dataProvider provide_shifts
    */
   function test_uintRShift($start,$shift,$end) {
      $this->assertEquals($end,uintRShift($start,$shift));
   }
}
```

For what it's worth the above mentioned function:

```
function uintRShift_branch($uint,$shift)
{
   if ($uint<0) {
      return ($uint>>$shift)+(2<<~$shift);
   } else {
      return $uint>>$shift;
   }
}
```

Fails automated test:

- **#4** Reports `-1`.  This can perhaps be justified by PHP reporting `0xffffffff` as a large positive number (documentation suggests large integers are automagically switched to floats, although the bit shift seems to treat it as a regular integer still)
- **#8** Results in `-2147483649` which is actually correct (same as `0x7fffffff`) but below the minimum int value for PHP:`-2147483648`