# Javascript triple greater than in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP shift right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325640/php-shift-right)

What is the ability to get the same result of javascript's [triple great than ( >>> )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/342xfs5s%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) in php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function urshift($n, $s) {
    return ($n >= 0) ? ($n >> $s) :
        (($n & 0x7fffffff) >> $s) | 
            (0x40000000 >> ($s - 1));
}
```

Untested, [credit goes here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?449434-Unsigned-right-bitwise-shift).

Comment: thanks it worked perfectly and sorry downvoters for not being clear or giving more details since i don't have enough info about what it is really, im just trying to transform javascript code into php, +1